# Creative exchange import warnings: "cannot relink image on item..."

Tags: sxa

I am trying to get rid of these warnings that I get when I use the creative exchange import. All the links in the html have been updated to the new location of those items automatically so I don't know what is still referencing the old location of the items.

This is what I get in the results window after the import:

[image]

Anyone has any ideas what the source of the problem might be?

Comment: Have you modified something after export? (`src` attribute of img tag)?

Comment: This usually happens if you have uploaded your media items in the Media Folder instead of Media Library/Your Site Name. So what happens is, when you do the export the first time, things looks fine but when you import them back, CE will create media items in the correct location but as Guids (see your item names, they are all with Guids).